# Neutral and Ground Bond for new Automatic Transfer Switch and Main disconnect Switch

Tags: electrical, grounding-and-bonding

I am working on a design where there is an existing transformer, generator, manual transfer switch and main panel. Where should I bond the neutral and ground for the new ATS and Main disconnect switch?

Comment: OK.  Is there a reason you're wanting to do transfer of the whole service, where is the existing MTS in this setup relative to the service (main) disconnect, and does your generator have a floating or a bonded neutral?

Answer (score 1):

The first disconnect past the meter.
Final answer.

It's not any more complicated than that.  Past that point neutral and ground run separately and won't ever connect again.

Ground is attached to local ground rods at each building, but no additional neutral bonds are made.

Comment: @Greg oops... thanks.